# What is the difference between "Kali On ARM" and "Kali On ARM (PiTail)"?

Tags: raspberry-pi, kali-linux, arm

The official website for Kali Linux has two versions for Raspberry Pi Zero W w ithout any explanation of the differences:

- Kali Raspberry Pi Zero W
- Kali Raspberry Pi Zero W (PiTail)

[image]

Same goes for the Raspberry Pi imager. It offers no details nor hits
[image]

### What is the different between each?

Answer (score 2):

### Raspberry Pi Zero W (PiTail) is optimized for tethering.

As explained on [the official Kali page](https://www.kali.org/docs/arm/raspberry-pi-zero-w-pi-tail/) for it:

> - Kali-Pi0 optimised for tethering
> - Simple, one cable solution for Bluetooth and Wi-Fi tether
> - Image, configure, connect, boot up in two minutes from scratch
> - Just install ConnectBot and VNC viewer on your smartphone
> - Automatic switch between USB ethernet and mass storage

Comment: As far as I can see, the reason is that it is specifically for a PiTail, but I can't find any documentation what this PiTail is.

Comment: ditto! + Very few info